# Show USB/BLUETOOH permission dialog over Android Kiosk mode

Tags: android, kiosk-mode

I've an application that is in Kiosk Mode (Screen pinning). The app's using the USB and Bluetooth to connect to perifferical devices. Every time i connect the USB i need to grant permissions, the bluetooth devices need pin's, but the system dialogs are blocked.

The lock code

```
public static final String [] APP_PACKAGES = {"com.example.app"};
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(activity, ApplicationAdmin.class);
    assert devicePolicyManager != null;
    if(devicePolicyManager.isAdminActive(componentName))
    {
        Log.d("LockTask", "Is admin");
        devicePolicyManager.setLockTaskPackages(componentName, APP_PACKAGES);

        if (devicePolicyManager.isLockTaskPermitted(context.getPackageName()))
        {
            Log.d("LockTask", "start locking");
            activity.startLockTask();
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("LockTask", "isLockTaskPermitted is false!!!");
        }
    }
```

Device admin xml

```
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-policies>
    <limit-password />
    <watch-login />
    <reset-password />
    <force-lock />
    <wipe-data />
</uses-policies>
```

It is working for USB if i put "com.android.systemui" in APP_PACKAGES, but then the user can exit the application by long pressing the home button.

For Bluetooth the above solution isn't working.

Is there a way to restrict to an bluetooth/usb package just to give acceess to the system dialogs?

Thank you!